# DRF - SerializerMethodField

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I've an API view as below:-

```
class ProfileAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        try:
            return Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        except:
            return None
            # I don't raise NotFound here for a reason.
            # I don't want a 404 response here, but a custom HTML response, explained below.



class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    html = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_html(self, obj):
        # some custom HTML response based on whether the user obj is `None` or not.
        if not obj:
            return NOT_LOGGED_IN_HTML

        return CUSTOM_HTML

    class Meta(object):
        model = Profile
        fields = ('html',)
```

Now when the user is logged-in, I get the `html` key in the response. However, when the user is None (logged-out), I get an empty response. Why? and how can I rectify it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can understand from implementation of [**`retrieve`**](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/0407a0df8a16fdac94bbd08d49143a74a88001cd/rest_framework/mixins.py#L56) and  [**`data`**](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/serializers.py#L248) method, you need to pass an instance of `Profile` to populate data. I would approach like this:

```
class ProfileAPI(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        try:
            return Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        except:
            return Profile()  # empty object instance


class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    html = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_html(self, obj):
        if obj and obj.pk:
            return CUSTOM_HTML
        return NOT_LOGGED_IN_HTML       

    class Meta(object):
        model = Profile
        fields = ('html',)
```